# Where I find mimeapps.list?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, qt

I am Installing Qt 5 on Ubuntu 14.04 using [this link](https://wiki.qt.io/Install_Qt_5_on_Ubuntu).

But, I am stuck to create **Qt-Creator.desktop** file. Document instructs that "open file **mimeapps.list** and check if the following line is present".

```
application/vnd.nokia.qt.qmakeprofile=qtcreator.desktop
```

But I can not find the **mimeapps.list** under the application folder.

So, Where I find **mimeapps.list**?

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9):

It should be in below directory:

```
/usr/share/applications/mimeapps.list
```

If its not be exists, you can create it, and put that line into this file:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/applications/mimeapps.list
```

---

Also you can create this file in your home directory:

```
nano ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list
```

And put this line into that file:

```
application/vnd.nokia.qt.qmakeprofile=qtcreator.desktop
```

---

For example my `mimeapps.list` file content is:

```
$ cat /usr/share/applications/mimeapps.list
[Default Applications]
application/wps-office.et=/usr/share//applications/wps-office-et.desktop
application/wps-office.ett=/usr/share//applications/wps-office-et.desktop
application/wps-office.xls=/usr/share//applications/wps-office-et.desktop
application/wps-office.xlt=/usr/share//applications/wps-office-et.desktop
application/vnd.ms-excel=/usr/share//applications/wps-office-et.desktop
application/msexcel=/usr/share//applications/wps-office-et.desktop
application/wps-office.xlsx=/usr/share//applications/wps-office-et.desktop
application/wps-office.xltx=/usr/share//applications/wps-office-et.desktop
vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroenabled.12=/usr/share//applications/wps-office-et.desktop
vnd.ms-excel.template.macroenabled.12=/usr/share//applications/wps-office-et.desktop
application/wps-office.dps=/usr/share//applications/wps-office-wpp.desktop
application/wps-office.dpt=/usr/share//applications/wps-office-wpp.desktop
application/wps-office.ppt=/usr/share//applications/wps-office-wpp.desktop
application/wps-office.pot=/usr/share//applications/wps-office-wpp.desktop
application/vnd.ms-powerpoint=/usr/share//applications/wps-office-wpp.desktop
application/vnd.mspowerpoint=/usr/share//applications/wps-office-wpp.desktop
application/powerpoint=/usr/share//applications/wps-office-wpp.desktop
application/wps-office.pptx=/usr/share//applications/wps-office-wpp.desktop
application/wps-office.potx=/usr/share//applications/wps-office-wpp.desktop
vnd.ms-powerpoint.presentation.macroenabled.12=/usr/share//applications/wps-office-wpp.desktop
vnd.ms-powerpoint.template.macroenabled.12=/usr/share//applications/wps-office-wpp.desktop
application/wps-office.wps=/usr/share//applications/wps-office-wps.desktop
application/wps-office.wpt=/usr/share//applications/wps-office-wps.desktop
application/wps-office.doc=/usr/share//applications/wps-office-wps.desktop
application/wps-office.dot=/usr/share//applications/wps-office-wps.desktop
application/vnd.ms-word=/usr/share//applications/wps-office-wps.desktop
application/msword=/usr/share//applications/wps-office-wps.desktop
application/msword-template=/usr/share//applications/wps-office-wps.desktop
wps-office-doc.png=/usr/share//applications/wps-office-wps.desktop
wps-office-dot.png=/usr/share//applications/wps-office-wps.desktop
```

---

For more information about MIME type default applications, please look at [this link in Arch linux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/default_applications#MIME_types).

Answer (score 3):

The `mimeapps.list` file contents and locations are specified by the [XDG MIME Applications Associations Specification](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/mime-apps-spec/).  [Version 1.0.1](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/mime-apps-spec/mime-apps-spec-1.0.1.html) specifies the lookup order as:

| Path | Purpose |
| --- | --- |
| `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/$desktop-mimeapps.list` | user overrides, desktop-specific (for advanced users) |
| `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/mimeapps.list` | user overrides (recommended location for user configuration GUIs) |
| `$XDG_CONFIG_DIRS/$desktop-mimeapps.list` | sysadmin and ISV overrides, desktop-specific |
| `$XDG_CONFIG_DIRS/mimeapps.list` | sysadmin and ISV overrides |
| `$XDG_DATA_HOME/applications/$desktop-mimeapps.list` | for completeness, deprecated, desktop-specific |
| `$XDG_DATA_HOME/applications/mimeapps.list` | for compatibility, deprecated |
| `$XDG_DATA_DIRS/applications/$desktop-mimeapps.list` | distribution-provided defaults, desktop-specific |
| `$XDG_DATA_DIRS/applications/mimeapps.list` | distribution-provided defaults |

Where `$desktop` is a lower-case value from `$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP`, which is defined along with the other `$XDG_` environment variables by the [XDG Base Directory Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html).  Assuming default values in the GNOME desktop environment, the lookup order would be:

1. `~/.config/gnome-mimeapps.list`
2. `~/.config/mimeapps.list`
3. `/etc/xdg/gnome-mimeapps.list`
4. `/etc/xdg/mimeapps.list`
5. `~/.local/share/applications/gnome-mimeapps.list`
6. `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`
7. `/usr/local/share/applications/gnome-mimeapps.list`
8. `/usr/local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`
9. `/usr/share/applications/gnome-mimeapps.list`
10. `/usr/share/applications/mimeapps.list`

Note that when finding the preferred application for a MIME type, the files are searched in order until a match is found, so adding a type to a file later in the list will have no effect if the type is present in a file earlier in the list.

You also may want to consider using a tool, such as xdg-mime from [xdg-utils](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/xdg-utils/) (e.g. `xdg-mime default qtcreator.desktop application/vnd.nokia.qt.qmakeprofile`), to set the association rather than editing `mimeapps.list` directly.